# c# LINQ to SQL dynamic where clause

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, dynamic

I'm trying to make a dynamic query to pull data from a sql database. But how do I accomplish a dynamic where clause for each item inside the listbox?

for example:

```
where datumStart <= fout.Datum && datumEnd >= fout.Datum && foreach (var item in listbox.SelectedItems)
{
    Treinen treinData = (Treinen)item;
    where fout.Treinen.Name == treinData.Name
}
```

So it adds all the items inside the foreach as a && where clause.

All the help is appreciated!

Source code:

```
            foreach (var items in _listBox.SelectedItems)
            {
                Treinen treinData = (Treinen)items;
                Console.WriteLine(treinData.Name);
            }
            DateTime datumStart = datePickerStart.SelectedDate.Value;
            DateTime datumEnd = datePickerEnd.SelectedDate.Value;

            ObjectQuery<Fouten> fouten = eventsEntities.Foutens;
            loadedData =
            (from fout in fouten
             where datumStart <= fout.Datum && datumEnd >= fout.Datum
             .....
             orderby fout.Datum, fout.Time

             select new
             {
                 Datum = fout.Datum,
                 Time = fout.Time,
                 FoutCode = fout.FoutCode,
                 Omschrijving = fout.Omschrijving,
                 Teller = fout.Teller,
                 Module = fout.Module.ToUpper(),
                 FoutId = fout.FoutId,
                 TreinId = fout.TreinId

             }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Fouten
             {
                 Datum = x.Datum,
                 Time = x.Time,
                 FoutCode = x.FoutCode,
                 Omschrijving = x.Omschrijving,
                 Teller = x.Teller,
                 Module = x.Module,
                 FoutId = x.FoutId,
                 TreinId = x.TreinId
             }).ToList();
            foutensDataGrid.ItemsSource = loadedData;
```

Comment: If the properties change in the where clause you'll need to use expression trees, otherwise you can use an expression if you are just changing the values in the where clause such as x.Name = "Bob" or x.Name = "Goostrabha" and pass the expression into the where as a predicate.

Comment: you can also add multiple 'where' clause to your query , each where clause means '&&' . so for instance, 'var query= select x where cluase1 where clause2'

Comment: What exactly should this *dynamic where clause* evaluate?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain calls to the `.Where()` extension method (and many other LINQ extension methods).  So first start with your collection (and your initial `.Where()` clause):

```
var foutens = eventsEntities.Foutens
              .Where(f => datumStart <= f.Datum && datumEnd >= f.Datum);
```

And then add `.Where()` clauses as needed:

```
foreach (var item in listbox.SelectedItems)
{
    Treinen treinData = (Treinen)item;
    foutens = foutens.Where(f => f.Treinen.Name == treinData.Name);
}
```

Then you can continue to add your remaining clauses, none of which actually evaluate the underlying data until you get to something which actually enumerates it (such as a `.ToList()` in your case):

```
loadedData = foutens.Select(f => new
{
    Datum = f.Datum,
    Time = f.Time,
    FoutCode = f.FoutCode,
    Omschrijving = f.Omschrijving,
    Teller = f.Teller,
    Module = f.Module.ToUpper(),
    FoutId = f.FoutId,
    TreinId = f.TreinId
}).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Fouten
{
    Datum = x.Datum,
    Time = x.Time,
    FoutCode = x.FoutCode,
    Omschrijving = x.Omschrijving,
    Teller = x.Teller,
    Module = x.Module,
    FoutId = x.FoutId,
    TreinId = x.TreinId
}).ToList();
```